# Bipolar stepper motor doesn't spin but vibrates

Tags: raspberry-pi, stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I got a problem with controlling a bipolar stepper motor. It doesn't spin but vibrates.
Here is the schematic of my stepper driver:
[image]
**DVDD** supplies 5v DC.

Here is the wiring map from the motor's specification:
[image]

here are the motor and how I wired it up to my PCB:
[image]
[image]

There are some hints about acceleration and high torque in the specs as well.

[image]
Full disclosure: I am not sure what to do with this info, I am not an electrical engineer.
Now, I have tried to write a simple python script to drive the stepper. However, all my best efforts ended up with the motor vibrating.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
 
delay = 0.005# time to settle
 
drv_m1 = 8 #GPIO08
drv_step = 20 #GPIO20
drv_dir = 26 #GPIO26
drv_nfault = 21 #GPIO21
 
def setup():
   GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
   GPIO.setup(drv_m1, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)
   GPIO.setup(drv_step, GPIO.OUT,initial=GPIO.LOW)
   GPIO.setup(drv_dir, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.HIGH)
   GPIO.setup(drv_nfault, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.HIGH)
 
 
setup()
 
try:
   while 1:
       GPIO.output(drv_step, 1)
       time.sleep(delay)
       GPIO.output(drv_step, 0)
       time.sleep(delay)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
   pass
GPIO.cleanup()
```

I have tried a varius delay values (between 0.0001 and 0.1) and tried out using PWM with frequencies as low as 100hz to 14000hz with no luck.

Any ideas what could be causing the problem here?

Comment: it could be the `0.005#` .... always leave a large space between code and comment ... also makes code less cluttered and easier to read

Comment: the schematic does not show a driver module that has `step` and `direction` inputs ... refer to the datasheet ... try bit-banging the outputs ... `Ain1 HI / Ain2 LO / Bin1 LO / Bin2 LO` ... `Ain1 LO / Ain2 LO / Bin1 HI / Bin2 LO` ... `Ain1 LO / Ain2 HI / Bin1 LO / Bin2 LO` ... etc etc

Comment: Always start the acceleration from zero then experiment with  max "a "or the ramp duration  especially with the added  torque load to start the pump. Once started, the acceleartion might be possible to increase to overcome the stiction.

Comment: Start with a link to the specs on the board and all the microcode installed.

Comment: DRV8428 stepper motor datasheets: (1) https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/2/477/DRV8428.php, (2) https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8428.pdf?ts=1642217715209&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.digchip.com%252F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong chip. The DRV8428P that you're using is not a stepper driver, it's just a dual H-bridge. Your code is therefore simply switching one of the stepper motor's coils on and off, making it vibrate.

You need an actual stepper motor driver that has "step" and "direction" input pins. Alternatively, you'll have to generate the waveforms for the stepper coils manually.

Comment: Why does the board with no spec link have stepper motor on the silk screen?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 It's most likely meant to be used as a H-bridge for driving a stepper motor with manually generated per-coil signals and not dir/step signals as the OP wants. Both the schematic and the picture of the board show that the DRV8428P is wired as a simple dual H-bridge.